# Dangers of using strip_tags in php forms?

Tags: php, forms, email

I created a php form that uses **strip_tags** to send mail to the client.  The form is not connected to any database.

What are the potential risks of malicious use?

Comment: "*I created a php form that uses strip_tags to send mail to the client.*" — `strip_tags` function is not capable of sending an email. Could you please clarify the question and include the relevant code so  we can understand it better?

Comment: I meant to say the form contains strip_tags in the source code. I just read that it isn't a good practice, but I'm looking to get more info if possible.

Comment: Seems like it might help answer the question: http://erosbence.blogspot.com/2011/09/striptags-is-not-enough.html

Comment: @AndrewNee thanks for the link. From what I get, it's more to do with preventing spam in the contents of the email itself, not with possible takeover of the form. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

The function strip_tags is used to filter out tags that might otherwise render something on the screen.

So it prevents the use of images, iframes, tables, layout.
This is probably not what you want.
You can however add a second parameter to the function with a list of tags that are allowed so  you can still keep the tags you need.

I don't think this is really handy if only you send the emails. If people using your website have the ability to send emails then it might be of help